# Proof of mean and vector

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be a random sample from $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$. Show that the sample mean and each $X_i-\bar X, i= 1,\ldots,n$, are iid. Actually $\bar X$ and the vector $(X_1-\bar X,\ldots,X_n-\bar X)$ are independent and this implies that $\bar X$ and the summation of the vector squared are independent. Thus we could find the joint distribution of $\bar X$ and $nS^2/\sigma^2$ using this result.

Answer (score 0):

Note: $\bar{X}$ and each $X_i-\bar{X}$ are *not* identically distributed: for instance, $\mathbb E[\bar{X}] \ne \mathbb E[X_i-\bar{X}]$, for non-zero mean $\mu$. However, to prove that $\bar{X}$ is independent of each $X_i-\bar{X}$, one can proceed using the following hints.

**Hints:**

1. Jointly normally distributed random variables that are uncorrelated are indepenedent [see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normally_distributed_and_uncorrelated_does_not_imply_independent);
2. Argue that $\bar{X}$ and the $X_i-\bar{X}$ are jointly normal by using the definition of joint normality and the fact that the $X_i$ are independent identically distributed samples from a Gaussian distribution;
3. Show that each pair of variables $\left\{\bar{X}, X_i-\bar{X}\right\}$ is uncorrelated.